# Access Windows Controls from another class or window

Tags: windows, visual-c++, mfc, findwindow

In an MFC program I am trying to access controls that are in one window (class) from another (sibling or daughter) window with code in a different .cpp file.  Typically you access a control with a DDX_Control variable defined in the class .cpp file.

```
DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_STATUS, m_Status);
```

The code for the other window is in a different file, so I don’t have access to the control variable (m_Status). What I have done is used FindWindow to find the main window, then GetDlgItem to find the control I am interested in:

```
CWnd * tmpWnd = CWnd::FindWindow(NULL,"MainWindow");  // find the main dialog box
CStatic * tmpStatus = (CStatic*) tmpWnd->GetDlgItem(IDC_Status);
tmpStatus->SetWindowText(“Status Report);
```

This works fine in the debugger, but fails when executed outside the debugger.  FindWindow gets the window ID correctly, but GetDlgItem returns null.

Ideally I’d like to access the control variable (m_Status) from the other window, but I don’ know how to do so.  I understand the GetDlgItem is less than ideal under any circumstance.

One solution would be to send a message to the main window class and tell it what to do, but I’d have to have a routine to handle each control and know how to handle whatever kind of data I am sending.

Is there a “right” way to do this?
Thank you

The ultimate answer is to cast to the original class:

((CspDlg *)AfxGetMainWnd())->m_Status.SetWindowText("Report");

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you created the "main" window you have an object or pointer for it. Or, you can call AfxGetMainWnd() to get a pointer to it. Then you can use that to access a public member such as m_Status.  All of your windows are interconnected and it should not be necessary to use FindWindow to find any window in your own program.

The fact that some variables may be defined in another file is not relevant. That can be handled with suitable use of #include "theotherfile.h" and object pointers/references.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I will try it and will post my results..  Yes, I can access the m_Status with an include, but as it is now it is not meaningful or I'm using it wrong.

Comment: Ok, I'm showing my ignorance here, but I'm still not sure how to access the m_Status control variable.  I have the .h file included, but the steps to access the control variable are not clear to me.  Please help if you can.  Thanks.

Comment: We need to see some code. Is m_Status a public member of the main window? Is it displayed at the time you want to access it? If so, (using your main window class name instead of CMain) this might do it for you: ((CMain*)AfxGetMainWnd())->m_Status.SetWindowText("Report");

Comment: That's exactly what I expected to work,but doesn't. Here's a simple way of looking at it:

    CWnd * mainWnd2 = AfxGetMainWnd();
    mainWnd2->m_Status;

Except that it doesn't find m_Status.  The .h file is included.  I'm not sure what code would be helpful.  Here is the ddx code in spDlg.cpp:  
    DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_STATUS, m_Status);

and the .h file:
    Public:
       CStatic m_Status;

Then I have a separate .cpp file with the code with the CWnd code above.  It has the include file:

    #include "spdlg.h"

I am missing something basic about accessing the public members of a class.

Comment: Yes, the something basic you are missing is that CWnd does not have a m_Status member. Cast the pointer to the actual main window class*, like the CMain I mentioned in the earlier comment.

Comment: I did that, cut and paste from your comment "((CMain*)AfxGetMainWnd())->m_Status.SetWindowText("Report");"   here are the error messages: error C2065: 'CMain' : undeclared identifier
 : error C2059: syntax error : ')'
1>: error C2039: 'm_Status' : is not a member of 'CWnd'
1>      : see declaration of 'CWnd'

Comment: Read my comment again. I told you what to use instead of CMain.

Comment: I think I got it.  I need to cast to the class with m_Status in it:((CspDlg *)AfxGetMainWnd())->m_Status.SetWindowText("Report");   This at least doesn't produce an error message.  Am testing now.  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: WOOT!  It worked!  Thank you very much, I appreciate your help and your patience.